# WPF binding validation not show error message

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have problem when try to validate username textbox field. When i lost focus i except to validator show error.

I create UsernameValidator class where impement `ValidationRule`

```
  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {

            if (this.username == null)
                return new ValidationResult(false, "value cannot be empty.");
            else
            {
                if (this.username.ToString().Length > 3)
                    return new ValidationResult
                    (false, "Name cannot be more than 3 characters long.");
            }
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
```

In xaml i set control template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Grid Width="12" Height="12">
            <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" 
            Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"

                     ></Ellipse>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Heavy" 
            FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"
                       ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, 
                       Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                       >X</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontWeight="12" Margin="2,0,0,0" 
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, 
                   Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                   ></TextBlock>                    
        </StackPanel>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder 
        x:Name="ErrorAdorner" ></AdornedElementPlaceholder>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And for my textBox username i declare

```
<TextBox x:Name="usernameTextBox" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="115,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277" PreviewKeyDown="OnUsernameTextBoxKeyDown">
<TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Username" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:UsernameValidator></local:UsernameValidator>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox
```

UsernameValidator class is my class for validating .

Program is successfull compailed whitout errors and warrnings.

I follow this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/690130/Simple-Validation-in-WPF

Answer (score 0):

WPF by-design silently fails binding operations (As in, nothing is displayed to the user during normal operation).

However when you run a WPF program under a debugger (such as the Run+Debug button in Visual Studio) then you'll see binding errors displayed in the Output window.

Comment: I try to compaile (Release) and try to run. The problem is the some. No error show. In debug i check output console and nothing

Comment: the Snoop utility is pretty handy for debugging binding errors.

Comment: Yup i try. But whay message is not show when i release app and when manual execute app.exe